# Добавление локального npm пакета

Tags: npm

Пытаюсь создать локальный пакет и подключить его в свой проект
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не правильно?

**UPDATE**

Попробовал сделать по другому, результат тот же

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя пакет и добавляется в node_modules

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а под подключить вы что имеете ввиду?

Comment: имеется в виду что бы в папке **test-app** я мог обращаться к пакету **my-package**. Буквально в **test-app/package.json** в секции scripts вызывается **my-package command-1**

Comment: вы можете обращаться к пакету. но секцию **scripts** вам надо обновить самостоятельно.

Comment: В каком смысле самостоятельно?

Comment: если вы в модуле **my-module** запустите `my-module start`, то у вас будет такая же ошибка. так как **my-module** не является самостоятельной командой. вам надо запускать примерно так `node my-module start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том что в **my-module/package.json** я указал секцию **bin** таким образом:

```
"bin": {
  "react-scripts": "bin/index.js"
}
```

Хотя должен был сделать так

```
"bin": {
  "react-scripts": "bin/index"
}
```

И в сам файл **bin/index** добавить в самое начало строку

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

А потом из папки **test-app** выполнить команду

```
yarn add file:../my-nodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Команда `yarn link` создает **symlink** (связь) между двумя директориями. В вашем случае команда `yarn link "my-package"` создала в директории **node_modules** в директории **test-app** **symlink** на директорию с модулем **my-package**.

Такая связь позволяет одному модулю использовать модуль установленный локально. Это удобно для отладки и для разработки.